# super keyword in generics

Tags: java, generics, super

```
  Set<? super TreeMap> setOfAllSuperTypeOfTreeMap  = new HashSet<SortedMap>();

  SortedMap<String,String> sm = new TreeMap<String,String>();
  TreeMap<String,String> tm = new TreeMap<String,String>();
  setOfAllSuperTypeOfTreeMap.add(sm); //???I do not understand at all. How then could new HashSet<SortedMap> be ok?
  setOfAllSuperTypeOfTreeMap.add(tm);
```

I do not understand at all. How then could new HashSet be declared at all? And what good does it do since SortedMaps can not be added anyway.

Comment: watch this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V1vQf4qyMXg#t=1339

Comment: Did the duplicate answer your question?